# SQL Server Compact stored procedure with multiple values in 1 input

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm using SQL Server Compact edition with the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[showAcResultsSorting]
   @RowsPerPage INT = 10,
   @PageNumber INT = 1,
   @sortBy VARCHAR(10) = updated,
   @favs VARCHAR(500)
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT *
   FROM acResults
   ORDER BY acUpdated
   OFFSET (@PageNumber-1)*@RowsPerPage ROWS
   FETCH NEXT @RowsPerPage ROWS ONLY
   WHERE acID = @favs
END 
RETURN 0
```

At present `@favs` is a single number, however I need to adapt the stored procedure so that `@favs` can accept a bunch of id's separated by commas, eg:

```
,1,,253,,67,,85,,1034,,84565,,154,
```

I recall reading something somewhere about being able to take the ids and turn them into a temporary table and then check against this temporary table. However, I can't find this article or similar. I don't even know if that would be the best way.

Comment: You didn't find this article?   http://vyaskn.tripod.com/passing_arrays_to_stored_procedures.htm   It's great.

Comment: That's not as concise as the one I saw previously, but its a decent alternative. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To split `CSV` to rows use this code

```
DECLARE @favs      VARCHAR(max)=',1,,253,,67,,85,,1034,,84565,,154,',
        @delimiter VARCHAR(10)=',,'

SELECT Rtrim(Ltrim(Split.a.value('.', 'Bigint'))) Result
FROM   (SELECT Cast ('<M>' + Replace(substring(@favs,2,len(@favs)-2), @delimiter, '</M><M>')
                     + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data) AS A
       CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
```

**Output :**

```
Result
------
1
253
67
85
1034
84565
154
```

Now you can use the above result in `where` clause using `IN` operator. Change your `select` inside SP something like this.

```
SELECT *
FROM   acResults
WHERE  acID IN (SELECT Rtrim(Ltrim(Split.a.value('.', 'Bigint')))
               FROM   (SELECT Cast ('<M>' + Replace(substring(@favs,2,len(@favs)-2), ',,', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data) AS A
                      CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)) 
ORDER BY acUpdated
   OFFSET (@PageNumber-1)*@RowsPerPage ROWSFETCH NEXT @RowsPerPage ROWS ONLY
```

**Example :**

```
DECLARE @favs      VARCHAR(max)=',1,,253,,67,,85,,1034,,84565,,154,',
        @delimiter VARCHAR(10)=',,'

SELECT 'works'
WHERE  convert(bigint,253) IN(SELECT Rtrim(Ltrim(Split.a.value('.', 'varchar(200)'))) Result
              FROM   (SELECT Cast ('<M>' + Replace(substring(@favs,2,len(@favs)-2), @delimiter, '</M><M>')
                                   + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data) AS A
                     CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a))
```

you can see the result : `works` even thought the sub-query is of `varchar` type it works

Comment: I'll give that a try asap, thanks. Is there anywhere I could read some sort of explanation of why exactly this does and why, for future reference?

Comment: I've hit a bit of a problem in that acID is actually a 'bigint' due to it being an autogenerated number used as the key. How can I factor this into your solution above? Thanks in advance and for the great help so far.

Comment: @PhillHealey - sorry i didn't get you. Can you explain a bit more

Comment: The comma delimited values are coming in to the SP as a varchar, but the value these are being checked against (acID) is a bigint. Therefore the SP won't compile as a result of not being able to do the conversion. I don't know how to rectify this to get the SQL above to work.

Comment: @PhillHealey - Even the subquery returns a numeric value in `varchar` datatype.  It will not throw error. But still i updated it to return `Bigint`. will give a example of that, check the answer.

Comment: I appreciate what you are saying but that is what VS Express was saying. The problem is that the varchar values in '@favs' need to be checked against the table column 'acID' and this column holds bigint values. Therefore there is a type mismatch between the '@favs' values and those stored in acID.

Comment: Ok, i see where problem is... The @favs value has an initial',' and another the end. Your xml trick doesn't account for those, but now that I know that is the issue, I can remove them before submitting the parameter to the SP.

Comment: @PhillHealey - oops didn't see that sorry, Now Leading and trailing commas has been handled. check the answer.

Comment: Ok thanks. Ive already adjusted my JS code to remove the prepending and appending ','. But it's good to have the update for future reference. Thanks for all the help. Have a great 2015!